# How to pass content from service to another service to controller with callbacks after it has been parsed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, csv, callback

I have a service that uses a callback function to pass content to a controller:

```
  angular.module('piApp').service("dataRetrievalService", function () {

  function getContents(callback) {
      //Converter Class 
      var fs = require("fs");
      var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
      var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("order.csv");
      //new converter instance 
      var converter = new Converter({ constructResult: true });
      //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
      converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
          console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object 
          //getResult(jsonObj)
          callback(jsonObj);
      });
      //read from file 
      fileStream.pipe(converter);
  }

  // public api
  return {
      getContents: getContents
  }
})
```

This service uses the [csvtojson node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) to get content from a csv file as JSON. And here is the controller that uses it:

```
angular.module('piApp').controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'dataRetrievalService', function ($scope, dataRetrievalService) {

     dataRetrievalService.getContents(function(contents) {
     $scope.result = contents;
     });

}]);
```

I'm wondering how I would properly move the parsing logic to another service that is injected into `dataRetrievalService` and still get the contents of the csv file to the controller after it has been parsed.

So my new `csvService` would be

```
angular.module('piApp').service("csvService", function () {
// public methods

function getCsvAsJSON(callback) {
    //Converter Class 
    var fs = require("fs");
    var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("Contents/Product Groups/orderTest2.csv");
    //new converter instance 
    var converter = new Converter({ constructResult: true });
    //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
    converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
        console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object 
        callback(jsonObj);
    });
    //read from file 
    fileStream.pipe(converter);
}


// public api
return {
    getCsvAsJSON: getCsvAsJSON
}
})
```

And my `dataRetrievalService` becomes something like

```
angular.module('piApp').service("dataRetrievalService", ['csvService', function (csvService) {

    function getContents() {

        csvService.getContents(function (contents) {
            this.result = contents; //should I be using another callback here instead?
        });
    }
    // public api
    return {
        getContents: getContents
    }
}])
```

I'm struggling to picture how this would work so that I pass a second callback to the controller and still get the desired content. How can I I pass the content from service to service to controller AFTER it has been parsed?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need any additional information or if I am being unclear.

This question is an extension of [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837062/how-to-pass-content-to-controller-from-service-after-it-is-done-being-parsed)

Comment: So what would `dataRetrievalService` service do then? Just call `csvService.getCsvAsJSON` or something else too?

Comment: @dfsq Yes there will other functionality in both services. The `csvService` will have different options such as `csvService.getCsvAsArray` and the `dataRetrievalService` will accept parameters so that it knows what view to get the data for, and if it should sort it. I just tried to keep it as simple as possible for this example.

Comment: use promises to chain?

Comment: use $q to chain this service and callback. It will be much easier for you. you can pass data when promise resolves. Also you can have reject(as error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good idea to separate loading and parsing routines. However, instead of callback it's more convenient to use promises. This is how services could look like in this case:

```
angular.module('piApp').service("csvService", function($q) {

    // public methods
    function getCsvAsJSON() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var fs = require("fs");
        var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("Contents/Product Groups/orderTest2.csv");
        var converter = new Converter({constructResult: true});
        converter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonObj) {
            deferred.resolve(jsonObj);
        });
        fileStream.pipe(converter);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getCsvAsJSON: getCsvAsJSON
    }
});

angular.module('piApp').service("dataRetrievalService", ['csvService', function(csvService) {

    function getContents() {
        return csvService.getCsvAsJSON();
    }

    return {
        getContents: getContents
    }
}]);

angular.module('piApp').controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'dataRetrievalService', function ($scope, dataRetrievalService) {

    dataRetrievalService.getContents().then(function(contents) {
        $scope.result = contents;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reaching out. I tried your suggested code and getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `dataRetrievalService.getContents.then(function(contents) {`, specifically at the `.then`. Any idea why this might be? I didn't need to download another script to be able to inject $q correct? I'll check my code and look into $q and promises. Let me know if you know what's causing this. Thank you very much for your help. I've haven't worked with $q or promises in the past

Comment: @dsfq I figured out my issue. The line should be `dataRetrievalService.getContents().then(function(contents)`. Your snippet was missing those parentheses but worked perfectly once I added them. Thank you so much!

Comment: oops, you are right, this should be a method call returning a promise, of course.