# How to pass content from service to another service where something happens to that content and it is then passed to a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

I am successfully parsing content in a service and passing that promise to another service. I would like to be able to do something to the resolved value of that promise and then store it in a way that it can be referenced from controllers that are injected with that service.

I'm not quite sure how to make this happen. Here is my attempt:

```
angular.module('test').service("service1", function($q) {
          function doSomething(something) {    
               //parses some data
               return deferred.promise;
           }
      }

      return {
          function1: function1
      }
});

 angular.module('test').service("service2", ['service1', function(service1) {
     function function1() {
         service1.doSomething("test").then(function (result) {
             var alteredResult = result + "Altered"; //I need to store this value so I can reference it from controllers that are injected with this service
         });
         return alteredResult;
     }
 }]);


angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'service2', function ($scope, service2) {

      $scope.test = service2.function1();

}]);
```

I am able to successfully pass the original promise from service to service to controller pass the promise and do the `.then` in the controller along with my alterations, but I would like to keep this logic in `service2`. I would like to be able to store this value in service2 so I can access it when I inject it into multiple controllers.

How can I get the altered content to be stored in my second service? Do I need to create a new promise?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need any additional info from me or if I am being unclear.

[Here is a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842354/how-to-pass-content-from-service-to-another-service-to-controller-with-callbacks) where someone helped me get the promise successfully passed from service to service to controller, so that it could be accessed and altered from the controller that may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the same value with multiple controllers you can store the altered value in an object in **service2** and expose that to the controllers.

```js
angular.module('test').service("service2", ['service1',
  function(service1) {
    // we're exposing an object with a null property
    var myResult = {
      alteredResult: null
    };

    function function1() {
      service1.doSomething("test").then(function(result) {
        // set the alteredResult property to the actual result
        myResult.alteredResult = result + "Altered";
      });

    }

    return {
      function1: function1,
      myResult: myResult
    };
  }
]);
```

In the controller you can then:

```js
angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'service2',
  function($scope, service2) {

    // get a reference the server's exposed object, it's alteredResult property will be filled in later.
    $scope.myservice2Result = service2.myResult;
    $scope.test = service2.function1();


  }
]);
```

If you need to return the result of the call in **service2** only to the caller then you can create a new promise.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I have a couple questions. Should the line in your controller read `var myservice2Value = service2.myResult;` instead of `var myservice2Value = service2.myValue;` ? When I followed your answer in my project, I `myResult` is still null in my controller. When I put some break points in, I see that function one doesn't change `alteredResult` until after the controller has already stored `myservice2Value` as null. Does that make sense to you? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: There were a couple errors in the example I gave. I corrected them now. The idea is that the object will expose an object that the controller can get a reference to. And after the http request ends we'll set our result as a property of the exposed object. That way any controller will cache that value. Also if you'll use $scope.myservice2Result.value in html angular will automatically show the new updated value after the request completes.

Comment: As a note, if you do not need to cache the value in the service, you might as well just make a new promise using $q and make it similar to the 1st service.